# how to configure nginx.conf file into httpd-ssl.conf as proxy server

Tags: apache, nginx

I am here to find some help in configuring `http-ssl.conf` file. We are using nginx as proxy server, but now we are trying to replace it with Apache HTTP Server (`httpd`) server. We have various proxy header set and `auth_request` set, for GUI page redirection.

I am stuck in setting `auth_request set` in `httpd`. I am struggling from almost one week, so can somebody please tell me how to set below configuration of nginx into httpd:

```
auth_request        /auth;
auth_request_set    $user $upstream_http_user;
auth_request_set    $role $upstream_http_role;
auth_request_set    $domain $upstream_http_domain;
proxy_set_header    user $user;
proxy_set_header    role $role;
proxy_set_header    domain $domain;

proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_redirect      /graph /xxxx/graph;
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find much on nginx `httpd` but as far as I understood that is a Apache protocol. Maybe this will help you:

> apachectl is a front end to the Apache HyperText Transfer Protocol
>   (HTTP) server. It is designed to help the administrator control the
>   functioning of the Apache httpd daemon.
>
> The apachectl script can operate in two modes. First, it can act as a
>   simple front-end to the httpd command that simply sets any necessary
>   environment variables and then invokes httpd, passing through any
>   command line arguments. Second, apachectl can act as a SysV init
>   script, taking simple one-word arguments like start, restart, and
>   stop, and translating them into appropriate signals to httpd.
>
> If your Apache installation uses non-standard paths, you will need to
>   edit the apachectl script to set the appropriate paths to the httpd
>   binary. You can also specify any necessary httpd command line
>   arguments. See the comments in the script for details.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/apachectl.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. but i am stuck in configuring above settings in httpd.conf. So can u please how can we configure above code into httpd

Comment: or any alternate configuration in httpd for this that i can use will be helpful..